# Allow a login form to process php script on same page without refreshing the page

Tags: php, html

**EDIT**
Thanks to, Wes C I now have this AJAX Code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form[name^='login']").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var dataToSend = 'username='+$("input[name^='username']").val()+'&password='+$("input[name^='password']").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == "REDIRECT")
                {
                    window.location = "business_profiles/myReviews.php";
                else
                {
                    $("#my_error_div").html(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But now instead of showing the error messages when you for instance type your password box. All I receive is an alert box saying "Success" regardless of what the forms input is.

Ok, I have tried and tried to figure this out on my own. As well as reached out to fellow coders and of course searched stackoverflow for answers. None really seemed to match my situation.

I have a simple login form like so:

```
<form name="login" action="index.php" method="post">

        <ul>

            <li>
                <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" autofocus="true"></li>

            <li>
                <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password"></li>
            <li>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"> <a href="register.php" id="button">Register</a> <a href="forgot.php" id="button">Forgot Password</a> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" id="button">Close</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

This form submits to the same page that it is on. (the php script is right above the login form.) and that is as follows:

```
    <?php

//If the user has submitted the form
if($_POST['username']){
    //protect the posted value then store them to variables
    $username = protect($_POST['username']);
    $password = protect($_POST['password']);

    //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
    if(!$username || !$password){
        //if not display an error message
        echo "<center>You need to fill in a <b>Username</b> and a <b>Password</b>!</center>";
    }else{
        //if the were continue checking

        //select all rows from the table where the username matches the one entered by the user
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

        //check if there was not a match
        if($num == 0){
            //if not display an error message
            echo "<center>The <b>Username</b> you supplied does not exist!</center>";
        }else{
            //if there was a match continue checking

            //select all rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

            //check if there was not a match
            if($num == 0){
                //if not display error message
                echo "<center>The <b>Password</b> you supplied does not match the one for that username!</center>";
            }else{
                //if there was continue checking

                //split all fields fom the correct row into an associative array
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

                //check to see if the user has not activated their account yet
                if($row['active'] != 1){
                    //if not display error message
                    echo "<center>You have not yet <b>Activated</b> your account!</center>";
                }else{
                    //if they have log them in

                    //set the login session storing there id - we use this to see if they are logged in or not
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
                    //show message
                    echo "<center>You have successfully logged in!</center>";

                    //update the online field to 50 seconds into the future
                    $time = date('U')+50;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");

                    //redirect them to the usersonline page
                    echo 'REDIRECT';

                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I am needing the form to process the script WITHOUT refreshing the page. My Login form is within a light box so in turn if there is an error like an invalid password when the page refreshes the light box hides again and you have to click Login again to find out what you did wrong. I just want the form to process the php script without refreshing the page so the light box never hides until the user has logged in successfully. Which then the user is redirected to their profile.

Comment: you mean something like AJAX?

Comment: For this scenario use `AJAX`.

Comment: So i would have to change all my coding for the script to AJAX?

Comment: No , write ajax script for calling the index.php.

Comment: No not all, but your form processing javascript would then prevent the default submit functionality of form and use AJAX to call your processing page to process your login. It's not a big change. Try something and then present it here if you cant make it work and someone will gladly assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery, you could post the data from the login form to the same page using the following AJAX function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form[name^='login']").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var dataToSend = 'username='+$("input[name^='username']").val()+'&password='+$("input[name^='password']").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function(response){
                if(response == "REDIRECT")
                {
                    window.location = "business_profiles/myReviews.php";
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error: "+response);
                    $("#my_error_div").html(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, change your PHP to:

```
<?php

//If the user has submitted the form
if(isset($_REQUEST['username'])){
    //protect the posted value then store them to variables
    $username = protect($_POST['username']);
    $password = protect($_POST['password']);

    //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
    if(!$username || !$password){
        //if not display an error message
        echo "<center>You need to fill in a <b>Username</b> and a <b>Password</b>!</center>";
    }else{
        //if the were continue checking

        //select all rows from the table where the username matches the one entered by the user
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

        //check if there was not a match
        if($num == 0){
            //if not display an error message
            echo "<center>The <b>Username</b> you supplied does not exist!</center>";
        }else{
            //if there was a match continue checking

            //select all rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);

            //check if there was not a match
            if($num == 0){
                //if not display error message
                echo "<center>The <b>Password</b> you supplied does not match the one for that username!</center>";
            }else{
                //if there was continue checking

                //split all fields fom the correct row into an associative array
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

                //check to see if the user has not activated their account yet
                if($row['active'] != 1){
                    //if not display error message
                    echo "<center>You have not yet <b>Activated</b> your account!</center>";
                }else{
                    //if they have log them in

                    //set the login session storing there id - we use this to see if they are logged in or not
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];


                    //update the online field to 50 seconds into the future
                    $time = date('U')+50;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");

                    //redirect them to the usersonline page
                    echo 'REDIRECT';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added the above code to my form and it still refreshed... Take a look at exactly what I am dealing with. (Click on Login and then type in a username and password and click login.) http://www.green-panda.com/review-pratt/index.php

Comment: Sorry about that! I modified the code above a little bit, which should fix the issue.

Comment: It is basically only running the ajax code and not the php code anymore.

Comment: Ok, to fix that, just change `if($_POST['submit']){` to `if($_POST['username']){`

Comment: It is still doing the same thing. No change. You may visit the site again to se exactly what is going on?

Comment: Hmm. Update your PHP to the code in my edited answer and see if it is still doing that.

Comment: Do I need to change something in my form tag? Currently it reads as:  <form name="login" action="index.php" method="post">

Comment: Try adding `exit;` near the end like above, and removing the `echo "<center>You have successfully logged in!</center>";` line

Comment: That just refreshes the page and loading the stops with only the background loaded.

Comment: Made some small changes to both the PHP and jQuery. Please use the updated code above and let me know what happens.

Comment: An alert box appears with all the pages code in it regardless of the information being correct or not.

Comment: I simply copied and pasted your answer into the page.

Comment: Ok, so in the PHP code, what does `$_POST['username']` contain when data has been posted to the page?

Comment: The username the user typed in the input field?

Comment: That's what it should contain, but for some reason PHP thinks that it is blank. What's the output of `print_r($_REQUEST);` when data is posted to the page?

Comment: I can't find out anything because all that happens is the alert box loading with all the pages code inside of it.

Comment: Load the page, upload the modified file with `print_r($_REQUEST);` at the top, then post the login form. Then let me know what the output is.

Comment: Thanks, try using `if(isset($_REQUEST['username'])){` at the top of the PHP code.

Comment: Same Story. Still receiving the alert box with all the ode in it regardless of whether the information is correct or not.

Comment: Just realized you said your PHP script is right above your login form. Move the PHP script to the top of the page, before any HTML code. We're getting warmer!

Comment: First, I would like to thank you SO MUCH for all the help you have provided! I moved the code and in result when you type information wrong you receive the correct error message in the alert box with no refresh of the page. (THAT IS WHAT WE WANT) When you type in the correct information... It does not redirect to the correct page it simply shows an alert box saying: Error: REDIRECT

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Glad it's pretty much working. Play around with the `if(response == "REDIRECT")` line, which should redirect the user if the response is equal to `REDIRECT`. Maybe try using `$.trim(response)`

Comment: Wow. That was almost too easy. I changed that code to if(response = "REDIRECT") and it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: Nope never mind it DID NOT now it redirects no matter what you type in. never mind.

Comment: It is simply displaying what is typed in the echo '' line of the PHP script. Not actually doing anything.

Comment: Very weird. Did you try the `$.trim(response)` ?

Comment: This is what I received: $.trim(response) 
$.trim(response) 
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/38/10473938/html/review-pratt/index.php:3) in /home/content/38/10473938/html/review-pratt/index.php on line 5
REDIRECT - See more at: http://www.green-panda.com/review-pratt/index.php?msg=WW91IGhhdmUgYmVlbiBzdWNjZXNzZnVsbHkgbG9nZ2VkIG91dCE%3D#sthash.GHz7W0LE.dpuf

Comment: Use it like: `if($.trim(response) == "REDIRECT")` in your jQuery

Comment: Oh my gosh! I think we finally got it. Sorry if I sounded stupid... I am not 100% up there with javascript and php quite yet. But thank you for all your help and it is now working 100% like I want it too. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

step1:Add a div to your login form.

step2: Validate the user controls and then load the page in the ajax call

step3:In the ajax success event append the page you want to show using `.html()`